# How can a docker service know about all other containers of the same service?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm working on a file sync Docker microservice.  Basically I will have a `file-sync` service that is global to the swarm (one on each node).  Each container in the service needs to peer with all the other containers on different nodes.  Files will be distributed across the nodes, not a complete duplicate copy.  Some files will reside on only certain nodes.  I want to be able to selectively copy a subset of the files from one node to another.

How can I get a list of the endpoints of all the other containers so the microservice can peer with the them?  This needs to happen programmatically.

On a related note, I'm wondering if a file-sync microservice is the best route for the solution I'm working on.

Basically I have some videos a user has uploaded.  I want to be able to encode them into different formats.  I was planning on having the video encoding node have the file-sync service pull the files, encode the videos, and then use the file-sync to push the encoded files back to the same server.  I know I can use some kind of object store but that isn't available to me with bare metal dedicated servers and I'd rather not deal with OpenStack if I don't need to.

Comment: If you're using VIP then you can do `nslookup tasks.<service_name>` and it will return the individual container locations. If you're using DNS then just `nslookup <service_name>` will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @johnharris85 for the above suggestion.  For anyone else that is interested I created a snippet that can be used in `node`.

https://gist.github.com/brennancheung/62d2abe16569e600d2be5e9495c85331

```js
const dns = require('dns')

function lookup (serviceName) {
  const tasks = `tasks.${serviceName}`
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dns.lookup(tasks, { all: true }, (err, addresses, family) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err)
      }
      const filtered = addresses.filter(address => address.family === 4)
      const ips = filtered.map(x => x.address)
      resolve(ips)
    })
  })
}

async function main () {
  const result = await lookup('hello')
  console.log(result)
}

main()
```